# How to change file icon in Turbo C++ and cc3270.dll

Tags: windows, turbo-c++

I started to use Borland's Turbo C++ a few days ago. I actually have two questions.

1.: How can i change the file icon?? If i create a program (Console Application), it will always have this blue icon (buildings or something like that on it), and i can't find it anywhere, how to change it to the default "none" icon (which like in Dev-C++ is the default).

2.: If i create a console application, and i want to run on my virtual pc, then it says that the CC3270.DLL is missing. If i copy it to c:\windows\system32\ then it will working perfectly. But i want to avoid this way. So is it possible, to change a setting or something like that, that my application won't need this file? It's disturbing beacuse, if i want to use my program on a computer which hasn't this dll, than i have to copy it there, on every machine.

Thanks in advance!

kampi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.you can see these links

- [How do I change the program icon for a console application?](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28893)
- [How to Create a Custom Program Icon for a Console Mode Application](http://www.decompile.com/cpp/faq/console_icon.htm)

2.If you build using the dynamic Run-Time Library, you will also have to distribute one or more of the Run-Time Library DLLs CC3270.DLL or CC3270MT.DLL and the memory manager DLL.

you must uncheck the option "build with runtime packages" located in the project options.

Bye.

Comment: Thank you ver much! I had some trouble with the icon thing, but i solved it :)